# Истинная дружба — она... очень трудно достижима / труднодостижима

Tags: орфография

Как корректно?

> Истинная дружба — она... очень трудно достижима / труднодостижима.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Истинная дружба — она... очень **трудно достижима.***

Наличие пояснительного слова ***очень*** переводит термин "труднодостижимый" в **свободное** словосочетание. Также использование термина **в краткой форме** вызывает сомнение.

[Пример](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0):

*Истина **трудно достижима,** и она постигается в упорной борьбе.*